# How to get the execution start time and end time (UTC format ) in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i need one help how can i get the below details when the XSLT transformation happens

1. execution start time for the XSLT
2. execution start time for the XSLT

both in UTC format - sample format - 2015-12-02T09:41:56Z

i tried below approach 
1. get the current date time but have the below issues
**issue 1** 
I do not know how the XSLT gets executed - googling to find out
`<xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/>`

**issue 2** 
i am getting the output in below format 
2015-12-02T16:08:19+05:1800000 - working on getting the format corrected.

NOTE i do not have the option to run the XSLT through command line.

source XML

```
 ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <xsltExecutionStartTime/>
    </book>
    <book>
        <xsltExecutionEndTime/>
    </book>
</books>`
```

XSLT

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
                xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"  
                exclude-result-prefixes="java"  xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"      extension-element-prefixes="ex" >  

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="4.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="startTime" select="ex:date-time()"/>
        <xsl:template match = "/">
            <xsltExecutionStartTime><xsl:value-of select="$startTime"/></xsltExecutionStartTime>
            <xsltExecutionEndTime><xsl:value-of select="$endTime"/></xsltExecutionEndTime>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="endTime" select="ex:date-time()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet> `
```

expected output

```
`<?xml version="4.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsltExecutionStartTime>2015-12-02T09:41:56Z</xsltExecutionStartTime>
<xsltExecutionEndTime>2015-12-02T09:41:56Z</xsltExecutionEndTime>
```

`    but the point over her i want to make is i actually do not know how the XSLT processor  transforms the XML. i.e the starting point of execution and the ending point of execution.  thnak you

Thank You
Regards
-Brijesh

Comment: "*i tried below approach*" What approach is that?

Comment: Show us a minimal example that illustrates what you're doing (source document and stylesheet), what output it produces, and what output you want instead. We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: @keshlam updated the post with the details

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you cannot assume anything about the order of execution for your xslt-rules. If you try calling the date-time() function first and last in the template matching /, and process the rest of the document between these two statements, you might get the result you want, but the processor might also optimize by giving you the same timestamt twice.

For example (untested):

```
    <xsl:template match = "/">
        <xsltExecutionStartTime><xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/></xsltExecutionStartTime>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        <xsltExecutionEndTime><xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/></xsltExecutionEndTime>
    </xsl:template>
```